# Cassandra Unable to gossip with any peers

Tags: cassandra

I have 2 nodes.. One of them in azure (node1) one of them in my computer (node2)

```
ip1 = VM's public IP 
ip2 = 192.168.1.33
```

in yaml file:

```
Node1:
listen_address= ip1
rpc_address= ip1
seed = ip1

Node2:
listen_address=ip2
rpc_address=ip2
seed=ip1
```

When I check if  oport 7000 is open on ip1, it shows open.
Node1 successfuly starting but in node 2 I'm getting Unable to gossip with any peers error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `broadcast_address` for node2 as your public IP - Azure couldn't route traffic into your private network..., and then setup your router so it will route incoming requests to your node2.

Comment: Sir I setup this to my other pc. Now I will replace azure to my other pc. How ı’m supposed to fix the problem. Where i need to change? 

İp1= my modem’s ip